# Hosting single intranet from multiple IIS servers

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, windows-server-2019, dfs-r, intranet

We have multiple physical locations at our company and each one has its own physical server, subnet, domain controller, Active Directory site etc.

I want to set up an intranet site on IIS that can be accessed at https://intranet.company.com

But instead of just hosting it from our central location, I would like each physical location to have a copy of the website and serve it to the computers at that location. I'm guessing this would be done with DFSR to keep the site's files in sync.

So for an example if I'm a client at location A and I go to https://intranet.company.com, I would like the server at location A to serve me the website. If the website is unavailable, then request it from the next next lowest cost location or the central location.

The main point is, I don't want the client to have to use a different URL for each physical location like siteA.company.com or siteB.company.com

Not asking for a step-by-step, but maybe just to point out some methods or best practice techniques to accomplish this. Or maybe this is the wrong way and I actually should host it from a single server. Lemme know what you think. Thanks guys.

Comment: why would you want to sync all the files over different locations instead using a central place?

Comment: Lets say the main location goes down for maintenance, power out, updates, etc. Now no one in the whole company can use the site. It will also load faster if you're getting it from your local server.

Comment: well since you basically do not provide enough information. normally you would have a cluster setup for this and that can be already load balancing

Comment: Ok that's perfect. I'll start doing some research on both. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

> "each one has its own physical server, subnet, domain controller, Active Directory site etc",

then you can configure DNS to map `https://intranet.company.com` to the local web server's IP address for each locations.

> "If the website is unavailable, then request it from the next next lowest cost location or the central location."

That's a much harder to achieve requirement, which usually requires load balancing setup and/or reverse proxy.